# Facebook - Accessing the posts that other people made on that person Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Doc.
Your app needs user_posts permission from the person who created the post or the person tagged in the post. Then your app can read:
Timeline posts from the person who gave you the permission.
**The posts that other people made on that person Timeline.**
The posts that other people have tagged that person in.

However using the graph explorer
V3.0/me/feed?fields=from,to,story,message

I am only able to get my posts and not posts that other users have made directly to my timeline/wall.

I am also not able to access the posts to another user timeline from the originators id either.

All users have the app installed and have given permission. ie. All users have given the user_posts and user_friends permissions
Any help would be appreciated.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps!!!

Reference:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/post

[As of April 4th, 2018, apps can no longer read Posts owned by non-app User who have been tagged by an app User.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOCuj.png)

Thanks